# Ubuntu 14.04 (python2.7) Errors were encountered while processing python3.4-minimal python3.4 python3 [...]

Tags: 14.04, apt, dpkg, python3, apport

I noticed I can't install/uninstall any packages with apt.
`apt-get install -f` returns lots of errors

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3.4-minimal
 python3.4
 python3
 ubuntu-drivers-common
 python3-distupgrade
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 update-manager-core
 update-notifier-common
 python3-problem-report
 python3-apport
 apport
 apport-gtk
 python3-libapparmor
 python3-apparmor
 apparmor-easyprof
 python3-apparmor-click
 click-apparmor
 python3-crypto
 update-notifier
 update-manager
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
 xdiagnose
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Everything started when I tried to remove pycharm-community, in order to update it to newer version.

It seems `python3` returns illegal instruction when I try to run it from a terminal.

Any idea how to fix it without reinstalling ubuntu?

Thank you,
Vlad

Comment: The summary isn't useful. Please edit your question to show the full command you were trying to run, and the first three complete error messages.